# Can't call a Bluetooth BroadcastReceiver method in a Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I have this Service class:

```
 public class BluetoothService extends Service {

    private static Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, intentFilter);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bluetoothReceiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
           //
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {        
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public static BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                TextView tvStatus = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvtatus);
                Messaging.appendMessage(tvStatus, Bluetooth.getDeviceState(state));
                if (Bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
                    Messaging.appendMessage(tvStatus, Bluetooth.showMessage());
                }               
            }
        }
    };  
}
```

And in my Activity class, I have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvStatus;
    private Intent intentBluetooth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       tvStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvtatus);

       intentBluetooth = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
       startService(intentBluetooth);
    }
}
```

The BroadcastReceiver method (bluetoothReceiver) in the Service class is never called. I don't know why. If I have the IntentFilter and the BroadcastReceiver codes above all in an Activity, then it works - but not in a [separate] Service. I'm stumped.

My AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.onegoal.androidexample"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0.0" 
        android:installLocation="auto"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" /> 

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
            android:debuggable="true" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <service android:name=".BluetoothService">
            </service>
        </application>  
    </manifest>
```

I'm new to Android so what I'm doing may not be the best. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: have you given Bluetooth permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I have these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Comment: have u register Receiver in Manifest and as @Lucifer said have u taken Permission?? Even i dont think u can do TextView tvStatus = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvtatus);
 in ur receiver..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe the fact that **your receiver is static** causing the problem.

`BroadcastReceiver` should never be static. it can cause lots of problems.

other really bad design problem with your code - holding reference to activity inside service, and using it to modify views is really wrong thing to do. it can cause easily to memory leek.
the right why to communicate between `Service` and `Activity` is by implement android's `Messanger`, or sending broadcasts between them via `BroadcastReceiver`.

if you'll listen to my advice - you won't be have to make your receiver static (I guess you've made it static only because you are using the mActivity static instance inside)
and I'm pretty sure it will solve your problem

you can read about `Messanger` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

sure you'll find lots of usage examples in the net.

example of broadcasting updates to the activity from service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    this.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bluetoothReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            updateUIWithNewState(state);
        }
    }
};

protected void updateUIWithNewState(int state) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("serviceUpdateReceivedAction");
    intent.putExtra("state", state);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

}
```

and that's the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(mServiceUpdatesReceiver, new IntentFilter("serviceUpdateReceivedAction"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mServiceUpdatesReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mServiceUpdatesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        // do what ever you want in the UI according to the state
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Making the receiver non-static makes no difference. I've seen the Messenger class before but can't find a way that this class can send progressive updated messages received from a BroadcastReceiver for an intent like BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE.

Comment: @Chuong: I don't want start arguing about if it is possible or not. if all what your receiver doing is settings text into textView, why you need the service for? that's classic reason for implement the receiver inside the activity

Comment: I'm not arguing with you. I'm just saying that I can't find a way to use Messenger class yet (because I don't know how). That's all. Hope it clears up any misunderstanding

Comment: @Chuong: wait a second, I'll write you in a minute example from my own project I'm using Messanger

Comment: @Chuong: you know what? - I think it is better for you using broadcasts instead.  you need to register your activity to some broadcast which your service will send. that's the second option I suggested in my answer. you need example of how to do that? anyway - that's good example I found: http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/

Comment: Yes, if you can show me an example. I would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, Tal. Let me try to implement your codes and I'll get back to you after my meeting.

Comment: Tal: I've tried your codes but neither the bluetoothReceiver method in Service class or the mServiceUpdatesReceiver method in the Activity class fired. I've put some debugging codes including a Toast command but none were called. Do you know why?

Comment: @Chuong: are you sure that your Service's onCreate() method been called? did you declarer your service in the manifest?

Comment: I've got this declared in the manifest: <service android:name="com.onegoal.service.BluetoothService" />. It's declared within the <application> group.

Comment: @Chuong: did you know for sure the service been launched? (the Service's onCreate method invoked)

Comment: \@Tal: Yes, it does get called but that's as far as it goes.

Comment: @Chuong: if that's the case. I really don't have other idea why it's not working.

Comment: I just redeclared the service as <service android:name=".BluetoothService" /> and it seems all the methods in the BluetoothService class are called. But the mServiceUpdatesReceiver method in Activity is not called. It's very strange. Do I need to declare this BroadcastReceiver method in the manifest as well? I didn't think I have to.

Comment: @Chuong: no, you don't need to declare it in the manifest. make sure you are using the same action string (in my example it called - serviceUpdateReceivedAction), but because I've registered the receiver inside the onResume(), and unregistered it inside onPuase - then when the activity is not forground (or device screen is close) the broadcast won't be received

Comment: @@Tal: How do suggest I get around the activity foreground issue, then? Any hint?...

Comment: @Chuong: if that's the reason it's not working, then the solution is easy - instead of register the receiver inside onResume - register it at onCreate.  instead of unregister it inside onPuase - unregister it inside onDestroy.

Comment: I tried that too, same result, onReceive method in Activity is never called. I saw in the log file that onCreate, onPause and onDestroy methods in the activity are called but not onReceive. I'm really stumped. I even googled for activity foreground solutions, tried those, but they don't work (maybe perhaps I don't fully understand the solutions presented)...

Comment: @Chuong: the only thing I can do is see your full code (the project). maybe then I'll see what's wrong.  if you'd like me to have a look - send it to talkanel@gmail.com

Comment: Tal: I have emailed you my project. Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: @Chuong: I've noticed your service never been stoped. do you aware of that?  there is a change that instance from old version of your service still runs in background, and never been stoped/changed)

Comment: add this code to your activity.onDestroy - Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
        stopService(intent);     I don't see reason why keep the service running after the activity destroyed.    then if you haven't done it before - remove complitly (uninstall) the application from the device/emulator, clean + rebuild the project, and try again

Comment: Yes, my bad. Just trawled through my log file and saw the warning from Android about not closing the service. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: also it's weird the service working at all - because the declaration in the manifest is not correct - ".BluetoothService"   it's not suppose to work because your sevice class is in another package.  change the package to the correct one, and rebuild, clean, uninstalling..

Comment: I know it's weird but I actually show this "Bluetooth Service::onReceive()" in the log file - and that's where I was stumped. Anyway, rebuilding project now...

Comment: maybe it worked because in some point the service were in another package, and because you didn't re-build the project - it still referring to the "old one.."

Comment: @Chuong: I think I know what can be the problem:  change: "serviceUpdateReceivedAction" string to "com.onegoal.androidtest.serviceUpdateReceivedAction"  according to the documentation - custom action name must start with the application's package

Comment: You did it, Tal. Finally, got the Service to display messages from the BroadcastReceiver - I changed the service name to the fully qualified equivalent name - and it work. I think you were spot on about the service point to another package - I don't know why yet but I'll find out. Have marked your answer above as correct. Is there a way I can grant you more points as you have helped me tremendously with this issue - it has plagued me for the last few days - finally have some closure.