# Can I catch an event if I move out of bluetooth range

Tags: android, bluetooth

How Can I catch an event if I move out of bluetooth range and again when I come in range.

I was trying to make a sort of alarm app when a pair of connected devices go out of range of each other.I struggle in detect while bluetooth device in out of range.Can u people guess this.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790030/cant-call-a-bluetooth-broadcastreceiver-method-in-a-service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006407/broadcast-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connecting-disconnecting

Comment: ya thanks venkat.I will like to give an alert while bluetooth device move in out of range.can u guess this algorithm.

Comment: you can raise an alert dialog from the broadcast receiver.