# How to build a Broadcast Receiver for Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to  build a Broadcast Receiver, that will listen for changes on my Phone by      Bluetooth, so when i looses signal from my device that I'm connected to I will receive a message on my phone.**

Comment: You can add following broadcast action listed in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html into your broadcast receiver.

Comment: find from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11790366/1835231

Comment: well Hat I have done so far is

Comment: well  I have done so far is created a Broadcast receiver like this 
------------------------------------------------


  public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction():
    if (action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED:)  ||action.equals("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED_REQUESTED)){
log.d("Z", received:Bluetooth Disconnected");
harSequene text = "Lost Signal";
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.Length_Long):
toast.show():
}
}

Comment: it looks like it wants to work, when i turn of the Bluetooth from the other device, and the phone recognizes the disconnection, it just give s me an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android SDK has a built in sample for a bluetooth chat application , you can refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) to find its location depending your SDK version.

In it you will find a file named as BluetoothChatService.java please refer to it, it has a very decent broadcast receiver built into it.

In it follwing functions are used to get the connection state,every time there is a change

```
/**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }



 * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }
```